# Android listView displaying all the items except the last item

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview, adapter

My ListView is not showing the last item in the list. I am extracting all the songs inside an album and displaying these through a ListView. The ListView is displaying all the songs fine except the last song.

I verified that the adapter contains the correct count and even the ListView contains the correct count. Its just the display that is wrong. Any ideas what I am missing here?

My layout file:

```
  <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  .......
  <ListView
     android:id="@+id/songList"
     android:layout_width="420dp" 
     android:layout_height="220dp"
     android:layout_x="84dp"
     android:layout_y="260dp"
     android:divider="@null"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:scrollingCache="false"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"         
     android:listSelector="#00000000"  >
  </ListView>
```

I have to use AbsoluteLayout because this is targeted for only one display with specific dimensions.

Comment: show your adapter class

Comment: I suggest you not to use absolute layout as it has been [deprecated since API level 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that your AbsoluteLayout is not the correct size for the device, therefore the last item of the ListView is being cut off.

Although I know that it's not what you want, try making the height of your ListView smaller -- a height you know will not take up the whole screen -- and see if you can see all items in your ListView.  From there, you can either adjust the rest of your layout to be flexible (what I recommend) or find out what the correct dimensions are for your AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: Thank you Lisa, it was a silly mistake. The layout height for the list was exceeding the total height

Comment: You're welcome.  I know because I have done this before too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Absolute layout at all in any of the case,try to manage using Relative Layout.
If you want to display list in some part of Screen then you should consider fragment.
Can you show us what exactly you want to show in screen